# Consecutivo en ventana modal bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

por favor me pueden ayudar con lo siguiente? tengo un archivo index.php que llama a una ventana modal y llama a un archivo .js
La ventana modal captura unos registros y llama a agregar.php el cual hace las validaciones y el insert en la base de datos.
El archivo app.js contiene lo siguiente:

```
    $( "#guardarDatos" ).submit(function( event ) {  
    var parametros = $(this).serialize();  
         $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "php/agregar.php",  
                data: parametros,  
                 beforeSend: function(objeto){  
                    $("#datos_ajax_register").html("Mensaje: Cargando...>>");  
                  },  
                success: function(datos){  
                $("#datos_ajax_register").html(datos);  
                load(1);  
              }  
        });  
      event.preventDefault();  
    });
```

Lo que requiero es que el usuario debe digitar un número de guia manualmente, como si fuese una factura, entonces a lo que guarde, debe asignar el número consecutivo en el campo de Guia, es decir si digita 100, va y guarda y luego el campo debe quedar en 101
Aquí un ejemplo gráfico..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Podrías recuperar la última guía que has insertado y guardarla en una variable de session, cookie o algo del estilo. Luego sería mostrar esa variable en ese campo.

Comment: Hola @Iñigo Irigoyen Erquicia, gracias por su ayuda, sin embargo no se donde hacerlo. Sería en el archivo agregar.php que es el que valida los campos y hace el insert en la bd?

Comment: Exacto, después de hacer el insert puedes recuperar la id y devolverla.

Comment: Ok, hasta ahí entiendo bien, pero ya que tengo es un botón que dice Nuevo registro el cual borra lo que hay en la Modal para agregar un nuevo registro, creo es más fácil al presionar el botón de Nuevo registro, simplemente que capture la guia que el usuario tiene en la ventana y le sume 1. Intenté hacer $guia = $guia + 1;  echo $guia; y lo hace bien pero solo al abrir la modal, una vez abierta no lo actualiza. Creo estoy haciendo algo mal, cómo capturo ese valor que hay en la pantalla y que al presionar el botón Nuevo Registro le sume 1 a lo capturado y lo ponga en el campo guia?  Gracias.

Comment: Antes de borrarla captura ese valor le sumas uno y se lo vuelves a asignar a ese campo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias a la orientación de Iñigo Irigoyen Erquicia y  Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas he podido hacer un código con Javascript para solucionar este caso.
Simplemente era capturar el valor del campo de Guia y con una función sumarle uno.
Luego se asigna el valor nuevamente al campo Guia de esta forma:

```
function sumar()
    {
        var valor1=verificar("txtGuia");
        document.getElementById("guardarDatos").reset();
        document.getElementById("txtGuia").value=parseInt(valor1)+1;
   }
```

Muchas gracias!